# Reproduce Google Maps Infowindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm making an website and I'm including google maps v3 with [jQuery Map Marker Plugin](http://www.welancers.com/jquery-map-marker-plugin/).
What I wanted to do is reproduce the default window from google maps and have something like this:

[image]

There's a way to reproduce this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin allow to append HTML in the last elem of the Json in the `baloon_text`.

```
{"latitude": "31.42", "longitude":"-98.61", "icon": "i.png", "baloon_text": ''}
```

So you can append your own HTML content for each marker. Based on this, you just have to reproduce what you want, and in this case the old *Google Maps InfoWindow*.

I've got some time, so I've made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hMWnL/) almost same I think, all you have to do is to play with `CSS` according to what you want to show exactly :)

Comment: Well I know I have to play with the baloon_text just want to know if anyone have the code of the original Google Maps infowindow, and you're fiddle is enough for me. Thank you so mutch ! :)

Comment: If you inspect the code you can see it but it´s not very well formatted and understandable :) Glad to have help !